# How to change the position of a view?

Tags: java, android, view, position

I have two views called `x and y` they are both black lines (for example I made the height of the x line is **1dp** and width **230dp** and as background filled with the color **black**).

Now i want to move the position of the lines `programmatically` (for example I want the y line **50dp** to the right of the orginal position).

Can someone help me how to do this?
I have tried things such as setpadding but the line doesn't move.
Thanks in advance!

(ps: my minimum sdk is set for 7 so i can't use the newest api's).

Answer (score 0):

**Old Answer**

> Have a look at the [Absolute Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), it allows you to position
>   child elements using x, y coordinates. It *is* deprecated but it's the
>   only way in Android to do real x,y coordinate positioning.
>
> I would ask what the main point behind what you are trying to do is
>   though? It sounds like you  started with a goal, were led down a path
>   and now are asking how to get to the end of that path, rather than
>   asking how to do what you need to do.

---

**Edited**

For drawing graphs have a look instead at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271248/how-to-draw-charts-in-android.

Using a Layout class to draw a chart will only lead to a really slow app, since the layout classes are designed for creating relatively static layouts, not drawing full graphics.

Instead use either the Canvas and draw your drawables yourself or use the graphing packages listed in the SO question I linked above.

Comment: Ok, thank you i will try this. I have a image a graph and with the 2 lines i want to make a cross at the point of the graph http://i50.tinypic.com/nbp3md.png

Comment: In that case **DONT** use the Absolute Layout. It won't work at all. I have updated my answer with a better option.